# What is the proper way for using generic types within a UserControl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, generics

For starters, maybe someone can help with naming the question a bit better.

**What I'm Trying To Accomplish:**

Below is a *very* simple example for what I'm trying to achieve, using only the basic working parts to be able to derive the solution I'm looking for.

I want to be able to create the following file in the .ascx.cs codebehind:

```
public partial class DynamicControl<T> : System.Web.UI.UserControl where T : class
{
    public List<T> Items;

    public void Add(T item) {
        Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Properly reference this within the .ascx file:

```
<% foreach (var item in Items) { %>
    <p>item.Name</p>
<% } %>
```

And load this into an .aspx file with a tag like so:

```
<custom:DynamicControl ID="DynamicControl1" ItemType="Person" runat="server" />
```

Or even in the .aspx.cs codebehind as:

```
DynamicControl1.ItemType = Type.GetType("Person");
```

Really, whatever is possible.

I just need a way of creating generic user controls across my website where I can set the item type programmatically (or in the tag) and work with it both the .ascx.cs and .ascx files, as well as the referencing .aspx file.

**What I've Tried:**

1) Creating a `DynamicControlBuilder` and inheriting the `ControlBuilder` class, then attaching this as an attribute using `[ControlBuilder(typeof(DynamicControlBuilder))]`. The result made it so the control wasn't adding the generic type to the .aspx.designer.cs file and also so the .ascx file wouldn't know how to render.

2) Creating an inner property of the `DynamicControl` class that used the generic types, only I couldn't find a good solution for a default member being something like `DynamicControl<dynamic>` or something along those lines--since obviously the object wouldn't be compatible at that point and I wouldn't get any autocomplete or compile time error handling.

3) Using a method that does something like `Add<T>(T item) where T : class`, for example, which is currently what I'm doing now... but if I want to add a ton of items to a single control, this just gets ugly. I don't want the developers to have to redeclare the type for every method every single time. It also doesn't solve the problem of having the `List<T> Items` there, which means I get no autocomplete from that end, which is also ugly.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why is this tagged WPF?

Comment: I couldn't think of a more appropriate tag for the UserControl, and I believe they are commonly associated with WPF. I'm happy to remove it if it's not the best tag for the question.

Comment: What if you define types like `DynamicFooControl : DynamicControl<Foo> {}`, `DynamicBarControl : DynamicControl<Bar> {}`, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask what you're trying to do?

If it's to display many different types of items, a better strategy would be to have an interface like IDisplayable that lists the properties needed to display the item.  Now any item can put on the interface and be able to be used by the control, and the control doesn't have to worry about knowing how to dig out display information from many different objects.

So your control just becomes 
public partial class DisplayItemsControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public List Items;

```
public void Add(IDisplayable item) {
    Items.Add(item);
}
```

}

And, given your example above, the interface would just be

public interface IDisplayable
{
    string Name{get;}
}

Comment: So I understand how to work with interfaces and add them to lists to achieve this result, but what I'm having difficulty with is specifically trying to create a UserControl that mimicks what an ASP Repeater can do using the ItemType property.

Comment: Not as familiar with that, but again, why?  You can use reflection along with a ItemName property to dynamically discover the value of a property of any item given.  However it will be slow, and doesn't make much sense as the UI programmer now needs to know the internals of any object they're going to use.  ASP does something similar - it creates a RepeaterItem facade, and populates the Name variable based up the source item's property value.